# jquery .svg('get') returns undefined

Tags: jquery, svg

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.svg.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var svg = $('#svgContainer').svg('get'); 
            console.log(svg); //Returns 'undefined'
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="svgContainer">

    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="900px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 900 300" enable-background="new 0 0 900 300" xml:space="preserve">
        <rect x="48" y="15" fill="#0071BC" width="259" height="259"/>
        <rect x="195" y="85" fill="#22B573" width="354" height="142"/>
        <rect x="498" y="21" opacity="0.5" fill="#D9E021" width="190" height="256"/>
        <rect x="606" y="45" fill="#0071BC" width="247" height="121"/>
    </svg>

</div>
```

Any idea why it's not returning anything?  Here's the [documentation](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html), but it's not much help. (I also tried with an svg object instead of inline)

Comment: According to the documentation you linked, you first need to `$('#svgContainer').svg();`

Comment: I think it can't `get` existing svg objects, only stuff created in code. not sure

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed that...It was late, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before everything else, call `svg()` on jQuery object with SVG, then do what you wanted:

```
var svg = $('#svgContainer').svg(); 
console.log(svg.svg('get'));
// Logs SVG instance
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rewuh/3/edit?html,js,console,output).

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it (the introduction [here](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html) describes this):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.svg.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#svgContainer').svg(); 
        var svg = $('#svgContainer').svg('get'); 
        console.log(svg); //Returns 'undefined'
    });
</script>
```